# Arrays of Objects - splice the highest value of all of the objects. Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you help me with this logical issue?

I have an array that has Object tasks inside, each task has a number of days to complete.

I have a function that .shift() the first item from an array, however, I need it to take out the task Object that's 'time' value is highest.

```
const assignableTasks = [
      {
        title: 'Design Framework',
        time: '5',
        sequential: 0,
        seqData: '',
      },
      {
        title: 'Design UI',
        time: '3',
        sequential: 0,
        seqData: '',
      },
      {
        title: 'Design Software',
        time: '10',
        sequential: 1,
        seqData: 'Design Framework',
      },
    ],
```

That is the design of the Array.

This is my function to take a task from the list and return it:

```
const fetchNewTask = () => {
    return assignableTasks.shift();
  };
```

With the above data in Tasks, it should take Design Software, then Design Framework, then Design UI.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This works pretty well,  I really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: You are welcome, even more if you have read the linked `sort` documentation. Then you as well might accept the beneath answer of mine (which was currently updated with an important ***Note***.

Answer (score 0):

[`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) your array by providing a custom `compare` function to this array method. Then proceed with your *shifting* approach.

**Note**

Be aware that due to a task object's structure each `time` property features the to be compared value as *string value*. Thus this value has to be explicitly casted into a *number value* in order to contribute to a correct (and non breaking) comparison result ...

```js
function fetchNewTask(task) {
  // does mutate the original
  // array reference.
  return task
    .sort((a, b) => Number(b.time) - Number(a.time))
    .shift();
};

const assignableTasks = [{
  title: 'Design Framework',
  time: '5',
  sequential: 0,
  seqData: '',
}, {
  title: 'Design UI',
  time: '3',
  sequential: 0,
  seqData: '',
}, {
  title: 'Design Software',
  time: '10',
  sequential: 1,
  seqData: 'Design Framework',
}];

console.log('assignableTasks :', assignableTasks);
console.log('fetchNewTask(assignableTasks) :', fetchNewTask(assignableTasks));
console.log('assignableTasks :', assignableTasks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```